# Background API POST that handle failure

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, asynchronous

In my iOS app users complete transactions which I need to post back to the server. I've created a function to do this:

```
static let configurationParam = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
static var manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configurationParam)

func postItemToServer(itemToPost:DemoItem) {
    let webServiceCallUrl = "..."

    var itemApiModel:[String: AnyObject] = [
        "ItemId": 123,
        "ItemName": itemToPost.Name!,
        //...
    ]

    ApiManager.manager.request(.POST, webServiceCallUrl, parameters: itemApiModel, encoding: .JSON)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                print("post success")
            case .Failure:
                print("SERVER RESPONSE: \(response.response?.statusCode)")
            }
    }
}
```

Currently I call this once a transaction is complete:

```
//... 

if(transactionCompleted!) {
    let apiManager = ApiManager()
    apiManager.postItemToServer(self.item)

    self.senderViewController!.performSegueWithIdentifier("TransactionCompletedSegue", sender: self)
}

//...
```

Where `DemoItem` is a CoreData object.

This all works as expected. However I need the ability to retry the POST request if it fails. For example if the network connection is down at the point of trying post to the server I need to automatically post the data once it becomes active again - at which point there may be several `DemoItem`'s which need to be synced.

I'm new to Swift. In a similar Xamarin app I had a status column in my SQLite database which I set to 'AwaitingSync'. I then had an async timer that ran every 30 seconds, queried the DB for any items which had status='AwaitingSync' and then tried to post them if they existed. If it succeed it updated the status in the DB. I could implement something along the same lines here - but I was never really happy with that implementation as I had a DB query every 30 seconds even if nothing had changed.

Finally, it needs to be still work if the app is terminated. For example any items which weren't synced before the app is killed should sync once the app is resumed. What's the best way to approach this?

---

### Edit

Based on Tom's answer I've created the following:

```
class SyncHelper {
    let serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.syncqueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    let managedContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    func StartSync() {

        //Run on serial queue so it can't be called twice at once
        dispatch_async(serialQueue, {

            //See if there are any items pending to sync
            if let itemsToSync = self.GetItemsToSync() {

                //Sync all pending items
                for itemToSync in itemsToSync {
                    self.SyncItemToServer(itemToSync)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private func GetItemsToSync() -> [DemoItem]? {
        var result:[DemoItem]?

        do {
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DemoItem")
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "awaitingSync = true", argumentArray: nil)
            result = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [DemoItem]
        } catch {
            //Handle error...
        }

        return result
    }

    private func SyncItemToServer(itemToSync:DemoItem) {
        let apiManager = ApiManager()

        //Try to post to the server
        apiManager.postItemToServer(itemToSync:DemoItem, completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
            if let _ = error {
                //An error has occurred - nothing need to happen as it will be picked up when the network is restored
                print("Sync failed")
            } else {
                print("Sync success")

                itemToSync.awaitingSync = false

                do {
                    try self.managedContext.save()
                } catch {
                    //Handle error...
                }

            }
        })
    }
}
```

I then call this when ever a transaction is completed:

```
//...
    if(transactionCompleted!) {
        let syncHelper = SyncHelper()
        syncHelper.StartSync()
    }
//...
```

And then finally I've used [Reachability.swift](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) to start the sync every time the network connection resumes:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var reachability:Reachability?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        //...

        //Setup the sync for when the network connection resumes
        do {
            reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                selector: "reachabilityChanged:",
                name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,
                object: reachability)

            try reachability!.startNotifier()

        } catch {
            print("Unable to create Reachability")
        }

        return true
    }

    func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {

        let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

        if reachability.isReachable() {
            print("Network reachable")

            let syncHelper = SyncHelper()
            syncHelper.StartSync()
        } else {
            print("Not reachable")
        }
    }
}
```

This all seems to be working. Is this approach ok and have I missed anything which would improve it? The only gap I can see is if the network connectivity is active however the server throws an error for some reason - I guess I could then add a button for the user to retry any pending items.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if your concern is whether the network connection is working, you shouldn't be polling at intervals. You should be using iOS's network reachability API to get notified when the network status changes. Apple provides a simple implementation of this and there are numerous alternative implementations online.

Since a sync status value **should** be a boolean flag, it's not as if a fetch request is a heavy-duty operation, especially if you use reachability. Not only should the fetch request be fast, you can update the flag after the fact in a single step-- use `NSBatchUpdateRequest` to set the flag to `false` on every instance you just sent to the server.

If you want to get the sync status out of the persistent store (not a bad idea since it's metadata), you'll need to maintain your own list of unsynced objects. The best way to do this is by tracking the `objectID` of the managed objects awaiting sync. That would be something like:

- Get the `objectID` of a newly changed managed object
- Convert that to an `NSURL` using `NSManagedObjectID`'s `URIRepresentation()` method.
- Put the `NSURL` on a list that you save somewhere, so it'll persist.

You can save the list in a file, in user defaults, or in the persistent store's own metadata.

When it's time to sync, you'd do something like:

- Get an `NSURL` from your list
- Convert that into an `NSManagedObjectID` using `managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation(url:NSURL)` (which is on `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`)
- Get the managed object for that ID `objectWithID:` on `NSManagedObjectContext`.
- Sync that object's data.

Then on a successful sync, remove entries from the list.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply. Based on your recommendation I've added a boolean flag to the CoreData entity and used Reachability.swift instead of polling every 30 seconds. I've added my implementation to my question - have I covered everything or is there a way I can improve on the implementation?